# Grails webtest: couldn't find webtest jar

Tags: grails, web-testing

I cannot run the webtests anymore on Grails 2.3.11. Running `grails test-app` I get this:

```
Error Fatal error running tests: couldn't find webtest jar.
Expression: webtestJarFile. Values: webtestJarFile = null (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

In the plugins section in `BuildConfig.groovy` I have:

```
test(":webtest:3.0.1") {
    excludes 'htmlunit'
}
```

I also tried without the `excludes`, but that doesn't help. `grails clean` didn't help either. This used to work, but I don't know which Grails upgrade exactly broke it.

Answer (score 1):

Once I was a big fan of canoo webtest, but the plugin for Grails is now outdated and I didn't get it to run on Grails 2.x, too.

I would suggest that, if you already have lots of webtest tests in your project, you split your project into the Grails and the Webtest part, downgrade your webtest project to a Grails version where you know they work (1.3.8 was the last version I know for sure that they work) and run them independently from your project. This can be easily achieved by specifying a baseUrl when you start your tests.

The best replacement for Webtests in a Grails project is now Spock together with Geb, but you'll miss the great Webtest reports. Lukily, there is this great project https://github.com/renatoathaydes/spock-reports which now provides spock reports which can be modified via templates. And the Film-Strip plugin (https://grails.org/plugin/film-strip) - of which I am the Author - will bring you back the screenshots. I am working on a plugin which will combine the spock reports with the geb screenshots in order to bring back something in the spirit of the webtest reports.

Beeing not a real answer to your question, I hope it provides a solution.